# ECS Fargate application container cannot establish connection with Postgres database container

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to use ecs-cli to push a two container docker compose file up to FARGATE ECS. This is for a preview environment only. The first container is `postgres:12` and the second is `hasura/graphql-engine:v1.3.3`

The **docker-compose.yml** looks like the following

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
         awslogs-group: tutorial
         awslogs-region: us-east-1
         awslogs-stream-prefix: postgres

  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.3.3
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres
      ## enable the console served by server
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      ## enable debugging mode. It is recommended to disable this in production
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
      ## uncomment next line to set an admin secret
      # HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: myadminsecretkey
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
         awslogs-group: tutorial
         awslogs-region: us-east-1
         awslogs-stream-prefix: hasura
volumes:
  db_data:
```

The **ecs-params.yml** looks like the following

```
version: 1
task_definition:
  ecs_network_mode: awsvpc
  task_role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::***:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
  task_execution_role: "arn:aws:iam::***:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
  task_size:
    cpu_limit: "256"
    mem_limit: "512"

run_params:
  network_configuration:
    awsvpc_configuration:
      subnets:
        - "subnet-***"
        - "subnet-***"
      security_groups:
        - "sg-***"
      assign_public_ip: "ENABLED"
```

I am using the following command line call to trigger the push

```
ecs-cli compose  --file docker-compose.yml --ecs-params ecs-params.yml --debug service up --deployment-max-percent 100 --deployment-min-healthy-percent 0 --region us-east-1 --cluster "{ARN CLUSTER VALUE}" --create-log-groups --launch-type "FARGATE"
```

In ECS I can see the new service created and its 1 Fargate task is spinning up. If I open the task, the containers move from PENDING -> RUNNING. After some time, the application container moves to STOPPED and then eventually the database container moves to STOPPED as well. Once this happens the task stops and a new task goes through the same cycle.

Here is the log for the application container
[image]

Here is the log for the database container
[image]

In the docker-compose I have tried changing the environment variable for the PG database connection string to both `postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres` and `postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@localhost:5432/postgres`, both result in the same issue.

Any idea what might be going on here? This is inspired from this article: https://dev.to/raphaelmansuy/10-minutes-to-deploy-a-docker-compose-stack-on-aws-illustrated-with-hasura-and-postgres-3f6e
The only difference is that article uses EC2, not Fargate.

Answer (score 0):

try and add

```
    links:
     - postgres
```

to your graphql-engine service instead of depends_on which doesn't seem to work with AWS ECS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).